# Problems with logic in retrieving data, missing filter value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm working with Node.js app with use of Express.js and MongoDB. I have page teachersData.ejs, where is form for searching information which were added to MongoDB (I'm using MongoDB Atlas for cloud savings of data). Here is how my page look like:

```
<%- include("partials/header") -%>

<div class="welcome" id="choose">
  <p>Choose options of search!</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <form method="post" action="/choice">
  <div class="form-group" id="deleteMethod">
    <h1 class="text-center">Form</h1>
    <label for="teacherSelectGet">Choose teacher</label>
    <select class="form-select" id="teacherSelectGet" name="teacherSelectGet" onchange="updateHiddenInputGet()">
      <option selected value="">Choose one variant</option>
      <% teachers.forEach(teacher => { %>
        <% if (teacher.name !== "Test person 1") { %>
          <option value="<%= teacher._id %>"><%= teacher.name %></option>
        <% } %>
      <% }); %>
    </select>
  </div>

  <!-- Add a hidden input field to store the selected teacher's name -->
  <input type="hidden" id="selectedTeacherNameGet" name="selectedTeacherNameGet">

    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <label for="yearCheckFrom">From</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control item" id="yearCheckFrom"  min="1972"
            max="2100" step="1" name="yearCheckFrom" placeholder="Year from">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <label for="yearCheckTo">To</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control item" id="yearCheckTo"  min="1972"
            max="2100" step="1" name="yearCheckTo" placeholder="Year to">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="Pub">
      <label for="typeOfPub">Type of publication</label>
      <select class="form-select" id="typeOfPub" name="typeOfPub">
        <option selected value="">Choose one variant</option>
        <option value="Monography">Monography</option>
        <option value="Magazine">Magazine</option>
        <option value="Textbook">Textbook</option>
        <option value="Manual">Manual</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-center">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block save-info"
            type="submit">Find data</button>
      </div>
  </form>
</div>

<%scientificPublications.forEach(spublication => {%>
  <div class="container fixTable">
    <main>
      <div class="row ">
        <table class="table" border="2">
          <div class="row">
          <thead class="table-primary">
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Name of teacher</th>
              <th scope="col">Type</th>
              <th scope="col">Year</th>
              <th scope="col">Name of publication</th>
              <th scope="col">ISSN</th>
              <th scope="col">Link</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr class="table-info">
                <td><%= spublication.info %></td>
                <td><%= spublication.typeOfsciencePub %></td>
                <td><%= spublication.yearOfsciencePub %></td>
                <td><%= spublication.nameOfsciencePub %></td>
                <td><%= spublication.issn %></td>
                <td><%= spublication.linkOfsciencePub %> </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
            </div>
          </table>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
<%})%>

<br><br>
<%methodicalPublications.forEach(mpublication => {%>
  <div class="container fixTable">
    <main>
      <div class="row ">
        <table class="table" border="2">
          <div class="row">
          <thead class="table-primary">
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Name of teacher</th>
              <th scope="col">Type</th>
              <th scope="col">Year</th>
              <th scope="col">Name of publication</th>
              <th scope="col">Link</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr class="table-info">
                <!-- <th scope="row">1</th> -->
                <td><%= mpublication.info %></td>
                <td><%= mpublication.typeOfmethodPub %></td>
                <td><%= mpublication.yearOfmethodPub %></td>
                <td><%= mpublication.nameOfmethodPub %></td>
                <td><%= mpublication.linkOfmethodPub %> </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
            </div>
          </table>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
<%})%>

<script>
 function updateHiddenInputGet() {
    var selectedTeacherGet = document.getElementById('teacherSelectGet');
    var hiddenInputGet = document.getElementById('selectedTeacherNameGet');
    hiddenInputGet.value = selectedTeacherGet.options[selectedTeacherGet.selectedIndex].text;
  }
</script>

<%- include("partials/footer") -%>
```

As you can see here is select list with options, where I retrieve all teachers names from my database. Then I want to implement some serverside logic with use of these fields from form as filters to receive neccessary data. Here is how my server code looks like:

```
app.post('/choice', async (req, res) => {
      try {
        // Extract the selected teacher's name from the form submission
        const selectedTeacherNameGet = req.body.selectedTeacherNameGet;
        const selectedTypeOfPub = req.body.typeOfPub;
        const selectedYearCheckFrom = req.body.yearCheckFrom;
        const selectedYearCheckTo = req.body.yearCheckTo;
        const fromYear = parseInt(selectedYearCheckFrom);
        const toYear = parseInt(selectedYearCheckTo);
        console.log(selectedTypeOfPub);
        const teachers = await User.find();
    
        if (fromYear > toYear) {
          return res.status(400).send('Start year should be less or equal end year');
        }
    

    if (selectedTypeOfPub && !selectedTeacherNameGet && !selectedYearCheckFrom && !selectedYearCheckTo) {
      // Handle the case when both the teacher's name and type of publication are selected
      // Query the database for publications with the specified teacher's name and type of publication
      const scientificPublications = await ScientificPublication.find({
        typeOfsciencePub: selectedTypeOfPub,
      });

      const methodicalPublications = await MethodicalPublication.find({
        typeOfmethodPub: selectedTypeOfPub,
      });

      // Render the template and pass the data
      return res.render('teachersData', {
        teachers, // You might need to pass the teachers array here if required
        scientificPublications,
        methodicalPublications,
        // selectedTeacherNameGet,
      });
    } else if (selectedTeacherNameGet && !selectedTypeOfPub && !selectedYearCheckFrom && !selectedYearCheckTo) {
    
       const scientificPublications = await ScientificPublication.find({
        info: selectedTeacherNameGet,
      });

      const methodicalPublications = await MethodicalPublication.find({
        info: selectedTeacherNameGet,
      });

      // Render the template and pass the data
      return res.render('teachersData', {
        teachers, // You might need to pass the teachers array here if required
        scientificPublications,
        methodicalPublications,
        // selectedTeacherNameGet,
      });
    } // some other conditions...
else if (!selectedYearCheckFrom && !selectedYearCheckTo && !selectedTypeOfPub && !selectedTeacherNameGet){
      const scientificPublications = await ScientificPublication.find({});
      const methodicalPublications = await MethodicalPublication.find({});
      return res.render('teachersData', {
        teachers, // You might need to pass the teachers array here if required
        scientificPublications,
        methodicalPublications,
        // selectedTeacherNameGet,
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle any errors that might occur during the data retrieval or rendering
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});
```

Here I have an issue with teachers name. If I choose in form from select list only name, for example, 'Test person 1', I receive necessary data. But if I choose again some other name, I receive data not about that person, but about whole database with all teachers. It seems that value in req.body.selectedTeacherNameGet is missing. The same happens if I choose nothing in form, data about whole teachers are displayed, but if again I want to receive data only on chosen name, the same data about whole teachers appears. I can't figure out if that problem is on my client side or server side. Can anybody suggest how to fix this, please?